# "Nesting" variables in Dynamic SQL - How do I keep valid syntax?

Tags: t-sql, nested, global-variables, dynamic-sql

I apologize if this has been asked and I am to dense to grok the answer.

I am trying to determine the best way to do the following:

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
, @Filter nvarchar(500)

SET @filter = 'WHERE value1 IN (''A'',''B'',''C'')'

SET @sql = '
DECLARE @Field nvarchar(50)

DECLARE process CURSOR FOR
SELECT value2
FROM table
'+@filter+'

OPEN process

FETCH NEXT FROM process
INTO @field

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN

EXEC stored_procedure
@field = @field
@filter = '+@filter+'

FETCH NEXT FROM process
INTO @field

END

CLOSE process
DEALLOCATE process
' print @sql execute sp_executesql @sql
```

The problem here is that it translates to

```
DECLARE @Field nvarchar(50)

DECLARE process CURSOR FOR
SELECT value2
FROM table
WHERE value1 IN ('A','B','C')

OPEN process

FETCH NEXT FROM process
INTO @field

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN

EXEC stored_procedure
@field = 'N'
@filter = 'WHERE value1 IN ('A','B','C')'

FETCH NEXT FROM process
INTO @field

END

CLOSE process
DEALLOCATE process
```

Of course in this leads to a syntax error at A, B, and C

I have tried a number of variations of `replace(@filter,','')` to correct this, but this doesn't seem to do me any good.

Ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
replace(@filter,'''','''''')
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this part

```
…
EXEC stored_procedure
@field = @field
@filter = '+@filter+'
…
```

like this

```
…
EXEC stored_procedure
@field = @field
@filter = '''+REPLACE(@filter, '''', '''''')+'''
…
```

Comment: Thanks so much; Works like a charm! I KNEW I was over-thinking it.